# Html helper Label for doesn't show the id

Tags: css, html-helper

I created a check box and the label for check box, i used html helper to do this:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m[i].checkExport)
 @Html.LabelFor(m=>m[i].checkExport)
```

To modify label, in CSS file I wrote:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label {    
    background: url('images/delete.png') no-repeat;
    height:17px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {    
    background: url('images/delete.png') no-repeat;
    height:17px;
}
```

Here is the code that automatically generated:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The checkExport field is required." name="[0].checkExport" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="[0].checkExport" type="hidden" value="false">
<label for="">checkExport</label>
```

There are three problems here are:

1. CSS doesnt effect to label (do not change the background)
2. The label for tag do not point to checkbox because it can not defind id of checkbox

   3. The label is not clickable

Answer (score 2):

To address each issue

> 1. CSS doesn't effect to label (do not change the background)

If you inspect the html your generating you will see that the `CheckBoxFor()` helper generates 2 inputs, `<input type="checkbox" ..>` followed by `<input type="hidden" ..>` and finally the `<label>` element. Your css selector (`input[type="checkbox"] + label`) is trying to find a label element immediately after a `input[type="checkbox"]` which does not exist because of the intermediate hidden input. One option is to use a [Following-sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#general-sibling-combinators)

```cs
<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].checkExport)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].checkExport)
</div>
```

```html
input[type="checkbox"] ~ label {
    ....
}
```

[Refer fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4xx9mgLn/)

> 2. The label for tag do not point to checkbox because it can not defind (sic) id of checkbox

This is an unfortunate side effect of the html helpers complying with previous html specifications.

The html helpers generate the `id` attribute from the property name, but to avoid a conflict with jQuery, replace any `.`, `[` and `]` characters with an underscore (`_`). In your case `[0].checkExport` would become `_0__checkExport`.

But in [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) an `id` attribute needed to start with a letter, so this would be invalid markup so the html helper just omits the attribute from the generated markup. You can view the [source code here](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.WebPages/Mvc/TagBuilder.cs), and the relevant section of code is

```
if (!Html401IdUtil.IsLetter(firstChar))
{
    // the first character must be a letter
    return null;
}
```

> 3. The label is not clickable

This is related to the point 2 because an `id` attribute is not generated for the checkbox and as a result the label element does not have a valid `for` attribute that points to the associated checkbox.

One way to solve this is to use a view model that contains a property for your collection, for example

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public List<myModel> MyCollection { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view

```
@model yourAssembly.MyViewModel
....
for (int i= 0; i < Model.MyCollection.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.MyCollection[i].checkExport)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyCollection[i].checkExport)
```

And your inputs will now be generated with `id` attributes and the label will include an associated `for` attribute associated with the checkbox and therefore 'clickable'.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="MyCollection_0__checkExport" name="MyCollection[i].checkExport" ../>
...
<label for="MyCollection_0__checkExport">checkExport</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Html 4 reasoning for banning the `[`/`_`. I think MVC should throw an exception in this case. If it doesn't fully support a collection as a model, I sure would've liked to have known about it rather than having to spend 3 hours trying to figure out why my IDs are missing and digging into the source code.

Answer (score 0):

your html code:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The checkExport field is required." name="[0].checkExport" type="checkbox" value="true">    
<input name="[0].checkExport" type="hidden" value="false">
<label for="">checkExport</label>
```

the input[type="checkbox"] + label will not work because your label is not just behind the checkbox, it is behind the input[type="hidden"], so ,you need to change the css to the below:

```
input[type="hidden"] + label {    
    background: url('images/delete.png') no-repeat;
    height:17px;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/rsq5e4qs/

Comment: check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/rsq5e4qs/, maybe you need to set the background-size for it

Comment: how to make label clickable

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/rsq5e4qs/1/, add id for checkbox, and set the for attribute to the id of checkbox, you may need to  read some document to learn how to set id or attribute in html-helper if you do not clear about it

Comment: i change this code, but there is a problem, if i only want to display the image. how can i do . If i delete like this <label for="click-target"></label> it will not show the background

Comment: if you only want to display the image  ,you just need to delete the text in the label and set some properties for label http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/rsq5e4qs/3/